# Why does assignment in boolean comparasion outputs like this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was experimenting with operators and assignments. Eventually, I found something interesting to myself. Can someone explain why output is like this?

```
Spm='Maria' 

Spam='Maria'

Spm=Spam and Spm==Spam

print(Spm) # shows True

print(Spam) # shows Maria
```

Comment: Because it is `spm = (spam and spam==spm)`.

Comment: Thanx a lot. Actually, it was easy!

Comment: Interestingly enough, if you had `Spm=Spam and Spam` the result won't be `True` but `Maria`

Answer (score 2):

The line `spm=spam and spam==spm`
is equivalent to `spm = (spam and spam == spm)`,
where `spam` evaluates to true because its a non-empty string and `spam == spm` is obviously true, so the `and` returns `True`. This is then assigned to `spm`.